# Error when printing URI in drupal Views

Tags: views, theming

I tried to print the Image field URI and the image field in the views-field.tpl and i got this error. 
Notice: Undefined index: field_photo in include() (line 6 of timeline.tpl.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 6 of timeline.tpl.php).

Here is my code

```
<li class="row no-margin">
    <div class="timeline-badge <?php print $fields['field_event']->content ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="<?php print $fields['field_event']->content ?>"><?php print $fields['field_icon']->content ?></div>
    <div class="timeline-panel">
        <div class="timeline-mins"><?php print $fields['field_minute']->content ?></div>    
        <div class="timeline-comment"><?php print $fields['field_comment']->content ?></div>
        <?php if($fields['field_photo']->content){  ?>
        <div class="timeline-photo">
        <a id="tml-photo" href="<?php  print $fields['uri']->content; ?>" title="<?php print $fields['field_comment']->content ?>">
        <?php print $fields['field_photo']->content ?>
        </a>    </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check if it has a value, you can add a check if it exists, so on row 6:

```
<?php if (isset($fields['fields_photo']->content) && $fields['fields_photo']->content) { ?>
```

Otherwise do a `<?php dpm($fields); ?>` to see what is actually available to use for your theme.

It couldn't be that you have set it to "Exclude from display"?

Answer (score 0):

For line 6, try:

```
<?php if(!empty($fields['field_photo']->content)){  ?>
```

or

```
<?php if($fields['field_photo']->content != NULL){  ?>
```

The above two codes checks if the field is not empty, which means it exists.